# How to remove gocloudly.com malwaare from firefox on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: malware

I already have Ad block Plus on Firefox, but sometimes by clicking on links, it randomly opens a new window redirecting to web pages strating by gocloudly.com.

I found that it's some sort of malware and already found some instructions to remove it in windows but can't find any to remove it in Ubuntu.

Also if there is any way to remove it will keeping my browser history and settings please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is to find out if the system is effecting just the one browser, user account, or device. To do this, firstly see if another device on the network is also seeing the issue. If it is, you have a problem on your network, so see the **Network Problem** section below. If it is not, try a different browser on the computer - if you still see the issue, you'll want the **Computer Problem** section. If you don't see the issue still, try create a new user profile - if this doesn't show the issue, check the **User Profile** section. If the error does show with the new user profile, check the **Browser Installation** section.

**Network Problem**

The network itself is probably compromised. This is usually because the DNS servers you are using have been changed on the network, which means whenever you request the address of a given site, the request goes to someone it shouldn't, who gives you the address of a pay to click advert or similar (thus profiteering from your web browsing). The best way to fix this is to configure your routers DNS settings - there are many options, I would recommend asking your ISP for the ones they provide, or using Google's free ones (4.4.4.4 and 8.8.8.8 if memory serves). If you're unsure how to do this, you might perform a factory reset. Keep in mind you may need to get information to set up your router again from your ISP, so make sure their contact center is open before proceeding.

**Computer Problem**

Here, I believe you have a local DNS issue. That is to say that your computer is configured the same way that the router is above, but by default the DHCP server on your network tells your computer to use the DNS server which it wants you to. It is possible to override this and specifically tell your computer to use another DNS server, and this is most likely what has happened. You can try looking at all of your network configurations including for network-manager, wpa-supplicant, dnsmasq, and so on. I won't go into individual detail, but this should point you in the right direction.

**User Profile**

This is where a nasty script has been attached to your profile using either something like a tampermonkey script, or as a plugin in its own right. In this instance you should disable all plugins and confirm that the issue does not reproduce. If it does, you will likely want to start looking in your user profile directory to find the nasty stuff. If it doesn't, re-enable the plugins one by one in the browser to see which one causes the problem, then uninstall it and check your user profile directory to ensure all traces of it are removed.

**Browser Installation**

This is where things get a bit difficult, as really I'm not sure how difficult this would be to do, but I believe it's possible to either add a modified binary, to modify the launcher (e.g firefox.desktop) file, or to modify the applications configuration so that it starts a process which hijacks your requests, or so that it makes changes to the application as it runs to modify your requests (e.g through memory manipulation or through giving it specific environment variables/launch parameters to set the DNS). At this point, your best option is to fully remove the browser and install from a PPA. If this does not work, try a portable version - if that does work, you might want to install it manually to somewhere such as `/opt/`, which will remove your ability to update it using the apt package manager. The difficult, really, is that the malware still exists on your system at this point and without a forensics analysis, it will be impossible to predict what exactly it has done or how to remove it.

Comment: The same behavior happened in the guest session, but also I found that it affects other machines in the house. My sister's laptop experience the same issue as well as my android phone!!!

Comment: When it happened on your sisters laptop or your phone, were you logged in to a sync account for Firefox? If not, it suggests that your router itself has been hijacked and pointed to some DNS servers that you really don't want to be using.

Comment: It happened today and I use chrome not Firefox on my phone.

Comment: OK in that case, if you have access, you should login to the router and check what DNS server is specified. If you need help doing that let me know what router you have and I'll find some specific guides. Generally, though, it's fairly obvious. You'll want to set your DNS server to probably 4.4.4.4 and 8.8.8.8 (primary and secondary, respectively), these are Google's ones. If you're uber paranoid, you should ask your ISP for theirs, since they are usually also free. There are also numerous free DNS services available but these are the obvious ones.

Comment: I can login to the router and get the DNS servers form my ISP, but could you please explain how will this solve the problem? Does this malware infects the router itself not the machines?

Comment: As it is happening on all devices, it looks like your requests are being hijacked on the network somewhere. Unless the malware has infected all of the machines you've seen it on (unlikely - especially given you're using two different browsers), the chances are it's changed your DNS servers to some which do this.

Comment: thanks a lot for your clarification, I'll change the DNS and report the results.

Comment: Good luck, note down the DNS address before you change it just incase.

Comment: resetting the router was the solution, everything is ok now :)

Comment: Reset to factory default? Good stuff. If you'd like I can update my answer to reflect the problem, but as I didn't specifically suggest that I'd understand if you wanted to post the actual solution yourself?

Comment: Actually your answer and replies was the key to the solution for me. Instead of changing the DNS, I thought a total reset to factory settings will do the trick and returns everything back to normal. please kindly modify the answer so that I can accept it as best solution. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Glad I could be of service :) I've updated the answer now to vaguely cover all scenarios, it's how I should have answered originally but it's hard to provide such an answer in a short time frame. Now it should cover all cases where a user is experiencing this issue, and provide guidance for how to either fix or begin to fix it regardless of the cause :)